# Can CAT6 cable cause troubles when setting up my Old Router as an Access-Point?

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireless-access-point, cat6

I have an issue with my old router, that I want to use as an Access Point in my apartment. Old Router got its DHCP disabled, a unique static IP and SSID assigned. I am using LAN-to-LAN ethernet ports.

When I connect it with the ISP modem (router1) directly with a single cable, it all works just fine. I can see both Wifi networks and router2 serves as a useful switch as well.

The problem comes up when I connect those two via in-wall installed CAT6 cable (+RJ45 sockets). This cable connects the main living room (router1) and my home office (desired place for router2). In this scenario, the router2 is dead, I cannot access its admin setup via browser anymore, router1 admin says its offline, router2 Wifi SSID is down (no internet connection).

Nevertheless, in-wall installed CAT6 cable in my home office works just fine when I connect it to a PC, laptop, PS4 etc.

Any hints or tips?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that its cat6 cable.

Most likely the cable is not correctly terminated for Ethernet (phone cabling typically  won't work as its daisy chained and may only have 1 pair connected - Ethernet requires point to point , or there is a break in the cable or its not punched down properly. (It could be a very long run - more then 100 metres by that's unlikely.

Get yourself an Ethernet tester(like [https://www.amazon.com/iMBAPrice-Network-Cable-Tester-Phone/dp/B01M63EMBQ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M63EMBQ) ) - it does not need to be expensive and check the cabling.

Comment: Thanks, though the office wall cable/socket works fine, as I am currently connected to it via standard UTP LAN cable. Only my old router doesn't want to run. Could it still be due to the wrong Ethernet cable termination? Many thanks!

Comment: Its possible.  Guessing a bit - If the cable is damaged or badly terminated, the signal could be degraded, or the old router may be negotiating a slower 100 megabit connection while the new router is getting confused.   Some ethernet devices have lights on them - do yours, and if so, what are they showing?  Can you advise what speed the ethernet interfaces are on the various devices are for others (100 megabit does not always negotiate crossover connections and only requires 2 pairs.  Not sure how relevant that is)

Comment: I see a green light blinking on router1 and no light on router2. Ethernet ports: 1x1000 Mbit/s and 3x100 Mbit/s. All previous tryouts were through 100 Mbit/s one. The stronger doesn't work, not even when I try to plug in my PC/Laptop. I guess you are right...

Comment: we checked the keystones, crimped them cables harder and now it works perfectly. Again, many great thanks for your help.